# Converting the Gravitational Constant

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, units

Hello all and thank you for reading.

I am creating a program in Unity where I recreate the earth-moon orbit. Unity struggles with numbers so large when I write code in meters and kilograms so I made my own units. 1 unit of mass = the earth's mass (5.9736f*10^24 kg). 1 unit of length is the Earth's Diameter (12,756,000m) and the distance between the earth and the moon at a supermoon is 28.222 units of length (360,000,000m). In this world, what is the gravitational constant? I have done the math in two ways and gotten answers orders of magnitude different. I am officially giving up and asking for help from the internet.

Any help is really appreciated and please show work, I am dying to know how this is done.

Comment: You need to specify an appropriate unit of *time* as well.

Comment: I was afraid someone would say this. Can I assume the framerate of the game is equal to a second?

Comment: It takes a month for the Moon to go around the Earth. Do you want the player to have to play for a month to see one orbit? If not, “game time” can’t be “orbit time”. But you can certainly update the screen once per second, if you want a jerky game.

Comment: If you want a value of $G$ that isn’t too big or small, you need to pick a unit of time like a day or a month.

Comment: Agreed. I am new to unity as well as physics. This issue is on my radar, but I wanted to get the question above squared away first. If you have Unity experience, I'd love some guidance on accelerating time.

Comment: I don’t know anything about Unity.

Comment: Ok, so if I wanted one unit of time = 1/2 the time it takes the moon to orbit (13.5 days). How would that affect the gravitational constant

Comment: If this is just for a game, I guess it doesn't need to be all that accurate, but computing the Moon's orbit properly isn't easy. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_precession & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_theory for details.

Comment: I assume you're computing orbits by numerical integration of the acceleration & velocity. Doing that without the errors getting out of control isn't easy, and people have been wrestling with this problem for centuries. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_methods_for_ordinary_differential_equations discusses this, and various ways to deal with it. It's often recommended to use a [symplectic integrator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_integrator) like Verlet, or [Leapfrog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leapfrog_integration) with Yoshida coefficients, in celestial mechanics sims.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SI value of the gravitational constant is

$$G=6.674\times 10^{-11}\frac{\text{meter}^3}{\text{kilogram}\,\text{second}^2}.$$

Define your new units (with the time unit taken from your comment):

$$1\text{ MyLengthUnit}=1.2756\times 10^7\text{ meters};$$

$$1\text{ MyMassUnit}=5.9736\times 10^{24}\text{ kilograms};$$

$$1\text{ MyTimeUnit}=13.5\text{ days}=1.1664\times 10^6\text{ seconds}.$$

Then in terms of your units, the SI units are

$$1\text{ meter}=\frac{1}{1.2756\times 10^7}\text{ MyLengthUnit};$$

$$1\text{ kilogram}=\frac{1}{5.9736\times 10^{24}}\text{ MyMassUnit};$$

$$1\text{ second}=\frac{1}{1.1664\times 10^6}\text{ MyTimeUnit}.$$

This means that

$$\begin{align}
G&=6.674\times 10^{-11}\frac{\left(\frac{1}{1.2756\times 10^7}\text{ MyLengthUnit}\right)^3}{\left(\frac{1}{5.9736\times 10^{24}}\text{ MyMassUnit}\right)\left(\frac{1}{1.1664\times 10^6}\text{ MyTimeUnit}\right)^2}\\
&=\frac{(6.674\times 10^{-11})(5.9736\times 10^{24})(1.1664\times 10^6)^2}{(1.2756\times 10^7)^3}\frac{\text{MyLengthUnit}^3}{\text{MyMassUnit}\,\text{MyTimeUnit}^2}\\
&=261321\frac{\text{MyLengthUnit}^3}{\text{MyMassUnit}\,\text{MyTimeUnit}^2}.
\end{align}$$

(I kept a few too many (in)significant digits in the final integral value.)

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is 1.4636*10^25

The unit is : Newton-"your unit for length"^2/"your unit for mass"^2

The Gravitational constant is the force between two unit mass separated with a distance between their centers equal to unit length.
In your case you know the unit mass and unit length.
Just use the law of gravitation of find the force.

F = (G * M^2)/R^2

where M is your unit mass = 5.9736*10^24 kg
and R is your unit length = 12,756,000 m

when you put this in a calculator you get the answer as 1.463623783*10^25
 (you can round this off).